# Run a gradle command from build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

To run a part of my gradle script, I normally open the command line and type

```
gradle swagger
```

how can I make Android Studio automatically run this command when it syncs the gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

[image]

This is the gradle tasks view that android studio provides.

Menu Bar -> View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle